# NSFetchResultsController w/ NSPredicate (relationship) vs. Basic NSFetchRequest (Pic Included)

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate

Here is an image of the relationship I am debating:
[image: Core Data Setup]

I have a UIScrollView setup as a horizontal scroller that scrolls between 3 different UIViewControllers (containing a UITableView of course and the required delegate methods, etc.)

Each ViewController in the UIScrollView loads a UITableView of a specific **MyObjectType**.
(E.g. ViewController1 loads a tableview of all **MyObjects** where its **type** == *MyObjectType.name*)

Does this make sense? You'll notice I've setup an inverse relationship between the objects. A *MyObjectType* can have many *MyObject*'s but a *MyObject* can only have a single *MyObjectType* associated to it.

When I first load one of the UIScrollView viewController's I need to determine what *MyObjectType* this UITableView is for. I have this working fine and I set the Table Header accordingly.

E.g. *`[type valueForKey:@"name"]`* where *type* is a fetched result NSManagedObject of *MyObjectType*.

The thing is I'm wondering, when I obtain this NSManagedObject of *MyObjectType* do I not also have access to a NSSet *array (ie. `[type valueForKey:@"objects"]`) which I can use as the UITableView's datasource? Would this work if after I *add* or *delete* an object I *save* the managedContext and then I always *`[tableView reloadData]`* ?

I'm guessing this would work, as long as I don't require the UITableView content to change and update dynamically as new *MyObject* of this type are added? For this we require a NSFetchedResultsController right?

Here is my code for loading **ALL** MyObject's into a UITableView (which works):

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"MyObject" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                          initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = 
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"transientSectionDate" 
                                               cacheName:@"Root"];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[sort release];
[fetchRequest release];
[theFetchedResultsController release];

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

Could someone PLEASE be as so kind to show my what actual *NSPredicate* declaration I need to correctly load **ONLY** MyObject's whose *MyObjectType.name* == *@"XXXXXX"*? Let's assume I already have a *MyObjectType.name* stored in a retained NSString inside the ViewController.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate format string would be:

```
@"ALL type.name=%@", typeName
```

However, since you do have a particular MyObjectType object, you already have direct access to the needed MyObject objects and don't have to waste time trying to fetch them. Just convert the set into a sorted array.

To keep apprised of ongoing changes while the table is active, implement `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` in the tableview datasource object. Then  send `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` to that particular MyObjectType object like so:

```
[anObjectType addObserver:self 
               forKeyPath:@"objects" 
                  options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) 
                  context:nil];
```

Now, whenever the `objects` value of that paticular MyObjectType changes, the tableview's datasource will be notified and can change the table.

See [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-178352) for details.

Comment: So implementing the `observerValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: will ensure that the NSSet table datasource for MyObjectType gets updated automatically when a new MyObject gets added of MyObjectType? This means I can abandon the entire NSFetchedResultsController?